# How can I force DNN to load a CSS file in the last position?

Tags: css, dotnetnuke, skin

I try to load a CSS file of skin in the last position of CSS files in the header.
I use the below code.

```
<dnn:DnnCssInclude runat="server" FilePath="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" PathNameAlias="" ForceProvider="DnnPageHeaderProvider" />
    <dnn:DnnCssInclude runat="server" FilePath="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" PathNameAlias="" ForceProvider="DnnPageHeaderProvider" />
    <dnn:DnnCssInclude runat="server" FilePath="https://cdn.linearicons.com/free/1.0.0/icon-font.min.css" PathNameAlias="" ForceProvider="DnnPageHeaderProvider" />
    <dnn:DnnCssInclude runat="server" FilePath="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,500|Poppins:300,regular,500&amp;subset=&amp;cdv=120" PathNameAlias="" ForceProvider="DnnPageHeaderProvider" />
    <dnn:DnnCssInclude runat="server" FilePath="skin.css" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" ForceProvider="DnnPageHeaderProvider" />
```

**skin.css** file loaded pre another CSS files!

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried with another filename? Note that skin.css is a specific filename: DNN will include it automaticaly when taking the current skin into account.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set a high number as the `Priority` - the default is 100.

You can see the properties available on here with the [Client Resource Management API](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/client-resource-management-api#43a0bfff-2499-4c12-03ce-512978a3a08c)

Here's what some of the [general value are for Priorities](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/client-resource-management-api#952022ee-f0ab-4cc7-f161-494d7ab30e27) to help you understand.